# Why isn't SuperUser on twitter?

Tags: discussion, twitter

I have one habit. Every time I stumble upon a good site, I bookmark it and search it on the Twitter. As I joined SuperUser. I searched for "superuser" on Twitter to follow it. But the search yielded nothing, so I want to ask **why isn't SuperUser on Twitter?** If it's there, then what is its user name?

I am really looking forward to follow it on Twitter.

Comment: http://twitter.com/Super_User/

Answer (score 19):

Why should it be?

Comment: because twitter is good for stay updated with ur favourite one's thats why....

Comment: superuser has RSS feeds - much, much more useful than twitter.

Comment: @Michael following on twitter is much, much easier than subscribing to RSS and keeping yourself in sync

Comment: i agree with chakrit

Comment: Wrong unless you already have a twitter account and do not have an RSS reader. Since RSS is far more widespread and does not depend on a third party, it is undeniably twitter which is less reliable, less useful and harder to use.

Comment: @ All I think it's a a vorm of taste, why shouldn't there be both, a twitter script which places the RSS feed on Twitter, both parties happy.

Comment: I use Twitter, I like it, but RSS certainly doesn't get the SPAM that Twitter does....

Answer (score 8):

Jeff Atwood is on Twitter under the [codinghorror](http://twitter.com/codinghorror) pseudonym - he quite often tweets about SuperUser (and StackOverflow, ServerFault, etc.) too.

Comment: I thought, "Atwood" was his pseudonym. ;-)

Comment: Well I follow the codinghorror one - curious that someone saw fit to downvote this 'ere answer though...

Answer (score 7):

We have many sites on twitter now.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/

Oddly enough "@superuser" is some kind of reserved username on Twitter, and we still haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You can plug to RSS feeds -- (look at the link on the bottom-right of this page).
And, if you must, [plug Twitter through **FeedMyTwitter**](http://www.feedmytwitter.com/) from there (now better named as [**twit robot**](http://twitrobot.com/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why some of you are in denial of the usefulness of Twitter.
There is no harm putting such a wonderful site on Twitter.
After all social networking is good for any site and its followers.

Comment: Your question is associated with your MSO account. e-mail team@stackoverflow.com and they should be able to sort it out for you.

Comment: Also associate your accounts between the sites and if you've got > 100 rep on at least one of them you'll get a 100 point bonus on each associated site.

Comment: Damn - first comment should read "Your question **isn't** associated with your MSO account".

Comment: Are you kidding me? I practically have sex with Twitter I like it so much, and even *I* can't see any reason that Super User should "be" on Twitter.

Comment: @Jeff: Does your wife know that?

Comment: Sex in 140 characters... Need I say more?

Comment: Think of the kid, though....doomed to be 140 characters forever.

Comment: Twitter reminds me of a mix of crappy text messages and useless Facebook status updates most days.

Answer (score 0):

Most people follow sites on Twitter so they can see the latest improvements and changes. If you'd like to follow the latest happenings with SuperUser and the other sites in the family, just follow the RSS feed for the [Meta <kbd>status-completed</kbd> tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed). Or for less detail just follow the [Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com).